# Unable to use csquote’s \enquote with lettrine

Tags: csquotes, lettrine, quotation

I’m not quite sure how to get csquote’s `\enquote` to work nicely with lettrine. Should I just enter `“` and `”` manually (see code block below)? (Note that I’m writing `“` manually because not even `` works in lettrine)

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\Iniciales}{EB Garamond Initials}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\Iniciales}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{“L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit.” Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output w/ code above]

Edit: EB Garamond Initials already provides the correct positioning of quotation marks. I’m just looking to see if it’s possible to use \enquote with lettrine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal document to your question. The following is related and possibly a duplicate of your question [Adding an Opening Pair of Quotes to a Lettrine Letter](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/587824)

Comment: The question @AlanMunn linked is highly relevant, but I'm not sure this one is a duplicate because of the `csquotes` involvement? But I'm not sure, because I tend to use the active character facility rather than `\enquote`, so perhaps that case is more straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, as @cfr said, Im not quite looking for the same thing as that question.

Comment: I suspect you may have to do this manually because `csquotes` likes things within groups and `lettrine` is presumably using a group so that e.g. colour doesn't spill over into the main text. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\enquote` for this job. I suggest a `\quotelettrine` command.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}
\usepackage[
  style=french,
]{csquotes}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\Iniciales}{EB Garamond Initials}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\Iniciales}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0.3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.2}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\quotelettrine}{mmm}{%
  \lettrine[ante=\csq@thequote@oopen]{#1}{#2}#3\csq@thequote@oclose
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\quotelettrine{L}{orem}{ ipsum dolor sit.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the `style=french` option, I get

[image]

If you want that the quote character is in the left margin, change the code into

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\quotelettrine}{mmm}{%
  \lettrine[ante=\llap{\csq@thequote@oopen}]{#1}{#2}#3\csq@thequote@oclose
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `\lettrine` command uses a box (`\llap`) around its first argument, making it definitely incompatible with the `\enquote` command (overlapping boxes et groups).

Btw. option `ante` should be used to code the entering quote:

```
\lettrine[ante=``]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit.’’ Lorem ipsum...
```

as the `\Iniciales` font doesn't have the quote character.

The `L` has a positive depth, you need to raise it a bit, you could try

```
\lettrine[ante=``,lraise=0.2]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit.’’ Lorem ipsum...
```

to get this output:

[image]